# Angular - {{}} not parsing in ng-model attribute tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add a number of checkboxes dynamically to my website, and filter based on their values.

I'm failing at the part where I add each filter to the filters object via ng-model.

```
<div ng-repeat="filter in menu.filters">
    <label>{{filter.title}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filters.filter{{$index+1}}" ng-true-value="{{filter.stub}}" ng-false-value='' />
</div>
```

However the `{{$index+1}}` or in fact ANY use of the `{{}}` in the ng-model attribute breaks the entire loop.

What am I missing?

This is the entire code for the page:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu_item_renderer.html">
    {{category.title}}
    <ul class="global-menu-category-list">
        <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories | filter:filters" ng-include="'menu_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="global-menu-link-list">
        <li ng-repeat="link in category.links | filter:filters">
            <a href="{{link.link}}">{{link.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>

<form>
    <div ng-repeat="filter in menu.filters">
        <label>{{filter.title}}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filters.filter($index+1)" ng-true-value="{{filter.stub}}" ng-false-value='' />
    </div>
</form>

<div id="#global-menu" data-feature="globalMenu">
    <ul id="global-menu-categories">
        <li ng-repeat="category in menu.categories" ng-include="'menu_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The goal is to have the checkboxes filter the menu items.

The model is as follows:

```
'menu' = {
   'filters': [
      {
         'title': 'Unified Communications',
         'stub': 'unified communications',
         'turnedOn': false
      },
      {
         'title': 'News',
         'stub': 'news',
         'turnedOn': false
      },
      {
         'title': 'Events',
         'stub': 'events',
         'turnedOn': false
      }
   ],

   'categories': [
      {
         'title': 'News, Events & Updates',
         'categories': [
            {
               'title': 'Top Stories',
               'links': [
                  {
                     'title': 'News Archives',
                     'link': 'news/archives'
                  },
                  {
                     'title': 'News Subscriptions',
                     'link': 'news/subscriptions'
                  },
                  {
                     'title': 'News Submissions',
                     'link': 'news/submissions'
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               'title': 'Upcoming Events',
               'links': [
                  {
                     'title': 'Past Events',
                     'link': 'events/past'
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         'links': [
            {
               'title': 'Competitive News',
               'link': '/news/competitive',
            },
            {
               'title': 'Leader Communications',
               'link': '/leader_communications',
            },
            {
               'title': 'Partner Regional News and Updates',
               'link': '/news/partner_regional',
            },
            {
               'title': 'Recent Updates',
               'link': '/news/recent',
            }
         ]
      }
   ] 
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option would be to build a model in JavaScript with all the filters, and on each, have a "turnedOn" property. Then bind that property to each checkbox.

```
$scope.filterList = [
    {title: "title1", turnedOn: false}
]

<div ng-repeat="filter in filterList ">
    <label>{{filter.title}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.turnedOn" />
</div>
```

Then use `filterList` to generate your filter object.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your model. What is `filters.filter{{$index+1}}` supposed to be doing?

Comment: The goal is to have each checkbox add a filter to the filters object, which can then be fed to the menu items to filter based on them.

Comment: Does the turnedOn value get attached to each menu item that needs to be filtered, or to each filter object?  I've added my model to the original question for further clarification.

Comment: Just to each filter object

Comment: Could you post an example of how I would link the filters to the menu list with the filter function please? I'm a little confused still about how this works.

Comment: I think you will need to use a custom filter. There are plenty of examples available. In your filter function, you will need some sort of a for loop to check category values against each selected filter.